# Is this syntax a pointer to a slice or a slice of pointers?

Tags: go

After looking at [this blog post](http://blog.golang.org/gos-declaration-syntax), I am still unclear about whether the following syntax means a slice of pointers or a pointer to a slice.

```
foo  []*int
```

Which one is it, and what is the general rule of thumb for this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a slice of pointers, just read from left to right: (`[]`) a slice of (`*`) pointers to (`int`) integer. On the other hand, `*[]int` would be (`*`) a pointer to (`[]`) a slice of (`int`) integers.

Answer (score 2):

That is a slice of int pointers. `[]` brackets come before the type so `*int` is the type in your example while `*[]int` is a pointer to an int array or *[]*int for a pointer to an array of int pointers.

Just as a matter of style I would generally avoid using `*[]int` syntax in favor or something like `foo := &[]int{}` which results in `foo` being a pointer to the start of a new int array.